# Несколько огромных атласов или много маленьких?

Tags: unity3d

Делаю игру в Unity, в игре должно быть много домов. Текстуры больших, многоквартирных домов очень удобно размножать по ширине и высоте, если текстура маленькая и отображает одну часть, но читал рекомендации о том, что все текстуры ради производительности нужно объединить в единую текстуру-атлас. Этот способ исключает возможность размножения текстуры по двум направлением, по одной ещё можно, если правильно разместить текстуры. Вопрос в том, много маленьких текстур - это сильный удар по производительности?

Comment: Совершенно непонятный вопрос. Что значит "размножать текстуры"? "Размножать в направлении"?

Answer (score 1):

Память под текстуры/атласы выделяеться так ... 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048 ... то есть если размер текстуры/атласа 50x100 в памяти это займёт 64x128.

Разниза между одним атласом 1024х1024 и четырьмя 512x512 не слишком велика, но 1024 картинки по 32х32 это ОЧЕНЬ грузно. Скорее зависит от нужды уровня, например нет смысла хранить текстуры всех скинов для персонажа в одном атласе, если использоваться будет только один на протяжении времени (уровня). Объединять их нужно логически. Но тексуры для, скажем "зимнего" типа уровня нет особого смысла разбивать если он умещается в приемлемы размер атласа.